# jQuery does events does not recognize updated attribute

Tags: jquery

I have a div with the attribute id="x", and I have a the following code in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#x').click(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('id');
         alert('something')
    });
});
```

Now whenever I click the div, the id attribute is removed and the message pops up. But when I click the element again, the message still pops up. How come this happens when the attribute was removed the first time it was clicked?

Comment: You are missing a single quote in your `alert` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one, so that this only happens once

```
$('#x').one('click', function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('id');
     alert('something)
});
```

[jQuery one();](http://api.jquery.com/one)

But it could be better to use event delegation so that is checks the id of the element on every click like

```
$(document).on('click', '#x', function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('id');
    alert('something)
});
```

Here is some info on why this happens.

with your code jQuery gets the element that has the id if `#` and then adds the event listener, at this point the event listener is not told to check the id before triggering the event, so the event will be attached to that element forever, whereas with the example above, every time the user clicks the document, jQuery will check the id of the `event.target` to see if it matches and then will trigger the callback.

Answer (score 3):

The element remain instantiate in jquery with its id.
try this it works fine:

```
$(document).on('click','#x',function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('id');
         alert('somethin');
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eSMz9/)

Answer (score 2):

Because the event is bound to the element on document ready. Removing the attribute won't stop the already bound event from firing. You would need to do `$(this).off('click')` if that's what you wanted.